# Load Rails partial with passed values using AJAX?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

In my Rails app users have folders, and inside these folders are posts that they can add. Right now I have the folders displaying in my view like this:

```
<% current_user.folders.each do |folder| %>
                    <a href='#' id="addSubmissions">
                        <div id="post-container">
                            <%= folder.title %> <p id="created-time">Created <%= folder.created_at.strftime("%e/%-m") %></p>
                        </div>
                    </a>    
                <% end %>
```

What I'd like to do is load the submissions associated with a folder into a div when the `#addSubmissions` link is clicked. I've tried testing it out with this:

```
$('#addSubmissions').click(function(){
        $('#post-container').append('<%= render :partial => 'contents', :locals => {:folder => folder } %>');
    });
```

But it seems like that render code actually needs to be local beforehand.

The **_contents.html.erb** partial works, and is pretty simple:

```
<%= folder.title %>
<% folder.submissions.each do |i| %>
 <%= i.title %>
<% end %>
```

How could I go about doing this? Again, I want to be able to click the link of a folder and load the submissions inside the folder into a div in the view. I'm thinking AJAX might be the solution, but I'm pretty new to Ruby so I don't know how to implement this.

Comment: I don't think it renders anything, escaping JS in asset's js files requires additional code, which, I suppose, you din't provide. Also, change id to class, it can't be several elements with same id on the page

Answer (score 0):

This way it won't work. You need contoller method, which responds to JS, because you are fetching pure ruby variables.

Instead of:

```
<a href='#' id="addSubmissions">
```

you might try:

```
<%= link_to folder_content_path(folder), :remote=>true, :class=> "addSubmissions", :id=>folder.title %>
<div class="post-container" id="<%= folder.title %>">
  <%= folder.title %> <p id="created-time">Created <%= folder.created_at.strftime("%e/%-m") %></p>
</div>
```

or other method name you want. Also note, that ID should be unique for page, otherwise you won't get expected result. Here I use folder name as ID, it probably unique, and it is easy way to find div we want modify with JS.

```
def folder_content
  @folder=Folder.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |f|
    f.js
  end
end
```

folder_content.js.erb:

```
$("#"+"<%=@folder.title %>").append('<%= j render :partial => 'contents', :locals => {:folder => @folder } %>');
```